# How to add phpcaptcha to OpenCart

Tags: php, opencart, captcha

Could someone please tell me how I can add the Phpcaptcha (secureimage) library to OpenCart?

So far I can show the image in the template file catalog\view\theme\default\template\information\contact.tpl:

```
<img id="captcha" src="system/library/securimage/securimage_show.php" alt="CAPTCHA Image" />
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('captcha').src = 'system/library/securimage/securimage_show.php?' + Math.random(); return false">
<img src="system/library/securimage/images/refresh.png" height="25" width="25" alt="Reload Image" onclick="this.blur()" align="bottom" border="0"></a>
<input type="text" id="captcha_code" name="captcha" size="31" maxlength="6" value="" onblur="check('captcha_code');" />
```

but I don't know what to do with the controller. Where and how do I load the Secureimage library and initialise the Secureimage class and set its variables and validate the image?

Will very much appreciate your help. Thank you.

[SOLVED]

I got it. In the catalog\controller\information\contact.php comment out and include this code in the validate():

```
//if (empty($this->session->data['captcha']) || ($this->session->data['captcha'] != $this->request->post['captcha'])) {
    //$this->error['captcha'] = $this->language->get('error_captcha');
//}

$this->load->library('securimage/securimage');
$captcha = new Securimage();
$captcha_code = (isset($_POST['captcha_code'])) ? $_POST['captcha_code'] : '';
$valid = $captcha->check($captcha_code);
if (!$valid) {
    $this->error['captcha'] = $this->language->get('error_captcha');
}
```

PS. Assuming the secureimage library is located in /system/library/secureimage

---

[ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION - DOESN't WORK YET]

I've added the securimage to the index.php:

```
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/securimage/securimage.php');
$registry->set('securimage', new Securimage($registry));
```

changed contact.tpl:

```
<img id="captcha" src="index.php?route=information/contact/securimage" alt="CAPTCHA Image" />
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('captcha').src = 'system/library/securimage/securimage_show.php?' + Math.random(); return false">
<img src="system/library/securimage/images/refresh.png" height="25" width="25" alt="Reload Image" onclick="this.blur()" align="bottom" border="0"></a>
```

the controller has:

```
if (empty($this->session->data['captcha']) || ($this->session->data['captcha'] != $this->request->post['captcha_code'])) {
    $this->error['captcha'] = $this->language->get('error_captcha');
}

public function securimage() {
$securimage = new Securimage();
$this->session->data['captcha'] = $securimage->getCode();
$securimage->show();
}
```

I've got the picture, but after POST, it gives me an error - it seems the code doesn't get verified.

Comment: Can't we use the default opencart captcha as in http://demo.opencart.com/index.php?route=information/contact ?

Comment: I don't want the default one, I want the Secureimage

Comment: There is no secure captcha these days :-) Since a human has to be able to read a captcha, there are services in China and India where humans decode them for a ridiculous fines (e.g. 1.000 captcha images for $10)... Long live the spamming and brute-forcing! Captcha's no longer serve as anti-bot protection, it only slows them down (a little)...

Comment: My form can be sent only once a minute and after 10 messages within an hour it suspends the IP for a day. Good luck for them :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the library file to `system/library/` folder.
2. Include the library file in `index.php` file like: (for reference check how the `customer.php` library file is added and used.)

   require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/secureimage.php');

   // Secure captcha  //add after $registry->set('customer', new Customer($registry));
    $registry->set('securecaptcha', new Securecaptcha($registry));
3. Add a new function for your new captcha image in `catalog/controller/information/contact.php` and generate the image. (refer the default `captcha` function)
4. In `catalog/view/theme/default/template/information/contact.tpl` (replace `default` with your theme folder name if you're not using the default theme), replace `<img src="index.php?route=information/contact/captcha" alt="" />` with your new function like `<img src="index.php?route=information/contact/securecaptchaimage" alt="" />`

Have a nice day !!

Comment: Sankar, did you mean to add require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/secureimage/secureimage.php'); to the root index.php? Thank you.

Comment: Updated answer. also please do check how the library file `customer.php` is used in opencart for more information.

Comment: Could you please tell me what the registry does? What does `set('customer', new Customer($registry))` do in this context? Do I need to set a new secureimage, e.g. `$registry->set('secureimage', new Secureimage($registry));` and then `secureimage` is exactly what appears in the image source path? Thanks.

Comment: Here's a great beginner guide for anyone who stumbles upon this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478995/how-to-become-an-opencart-guru

Comment: I've updated the question. The controller doesn't check the code for some reason.

Comment: Do I understand this right: if i have this in the template: `<img id="captcha" src="index.php?route=information/contact/securimage" alt="CAPTCHA Image" />`, then my controller function must be the same name `public function securimage()`? Also, I've set the 'securimage' in registry, but if I do this: `$this->securimage->show();`, the page stops loading, it's blank

Comment: Then I think there may be some issue with your library file. Please check how the other library files are included, coded and used. If your code is correct, then you'll get the image when you call `http://yourdomain.com/index.php?route=information/contact/securecaptchaimage` like  http://demo.opencart.com/index.php?route=information/contact/captcha

Comment: If you look at my question above, the [SOLVED] part works without a problem. But it's not consistent with the way OpenCart is coded. I'd like to use OC's way, so when I try the [ALTERNATIVE] solution above, it doesn't work. The library loads fine as the first part works. I may be missing something in the controller. How do I show the image? Is `$this->securimage->show();` correct way? Thanks

Comment: Do I need to load the library again and instantiate the securimage class in the controller's function or if it's done once in the registry, then it should be available throughtout the program? Do I need to load the registry in the controller? BTW, I couldn't find where the Customer class is used.

Comment: `$this->securimage->show();` - correct. No need to load the library again. `I couldn't find where the Customer class is used.` - means you've not researched much. If you have even checked the header controller (`catalog/controller/common/header.php`), you must have seen the call to customer library file like: `$this->customer->getFirstName();`, 
`$this->customer->isLogged();` etc.

Comment: I've seen `$this->customer->isLogged();` nearly in many files, but I meant I couldn't find more. That's where I got `$this->securimage->show();`. But the image either doesn't show or the page doesn't load. Is `<img id="captcha" src="index.php?route=information/contact/securimage" alt="CAPTCHA Image" />` correct? How do I get the image code? Again, if I use `$this->session->data['captcha'] = $this->securimage->getCode();` I get a blank page (no errors in the log though)

Comment: I've got some progress, wasn't me, maybe cache or browser, it drove me nuts, no matter what I tried I had either errors or blank pages. I closed everything and started with a clean function. Now I can see an image with `mysite.com/index.php?route=information/contact/securimage`! My function securimage() has 2 lines: `$this->session->data['captcha'] = $this->securimage->getCode();` and `$this->securimage->show();`. So this works fine now. The form shows. But it does not verify the code. I'm using the exsisting original validate function in the controller. What could be wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Make sure that the `$this->securimage->getCode()` returns the captcha code. The `validate` function in that file validates the form like : `if (empty($this->session->data['captcha']) || ($this->session->data['captcha'] != $this->request->post['captcha'])) {`.

Comment: I've checked what `$this->securimage->getCode();` returns and it's 2 submissions behind. Thank is, the form loads, then it's submitted, then it's submitted again and now the code is what it was 2 steps back. How does this work?

Comment: During validate the `$this->error['name'] = $this->request->post['captcha'];` returns the entered code which is the same as was shown on the picture before Submit, while the `$this->error['captcha'] = $this->session->data['captcha'];` returns the code which was entered 2 submits before

Comment: always make sure that the code in image and the code returned are the same. i cannot debug your code.